# popToRootViewControllerView

Tags: iphone

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

It looks like the above in the delegate is setting the initial view as the root view. Is that true? Or is it setting the current view each time? How dpi set the initial view as the root view?

Because when I'm on my 3rd view and want to pop back to initial view its not happening:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a `UINavigationController`? If so, you should have code in your `AppDelegate` that looks like:

```
[window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Make sure that you do have a `UINavigationController` hooked up, otherwise, you won't be able to use methods like:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Hope that Helps!

Comment: Thanks MSgambel thats sounds advice off the bat, let me try it out.